# Testing PHP POST empty values - unexpected result - What am I missing?

Tags: php

I am following a tutorial but I keep getting a TRUE result that shouldn't be correct if I click the submit button WITHOUT filling in any value in the name field.
The first test works as expected, but the second and third test keep returning TRUE when they should return FALSE (leaving the input empty).

What am I missing, not understanding, or doing wrong?  This should be simple.
Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Here is the very simple script:

```
<?php
//This one works correctly
if(!empty($_POST['name'])) {
    echo "There is input here <br>";
} else {
    echo "You have not input any info yet. <br>";
}

//This returns true even if I leave the field empty
if(isset($_POST['name'])) {
    echo "A name has been input <br>";
} else {
    echo "You have not input your name yet. <br>";
}
//This returns true also when it shouldn't
if(filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'name')) {
    echo $_POST['name'] . ' <- Name Input!<br>';
} else {
    echo 'No Name Input.';
}

?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    <p><label for="name">Name:</label> <input type="text" name="name" 
id="name" size="30" value=""></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="SEND"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: That input (of type text) variable is always set on submit. What were you expecting? ;)

Comment: Don't check if it is empty... check if it != ""

Comment: use isset() to see if a variable exists and use empty() to check if the variable has value or not.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I am not sure what to expect, but I thought I should expect the condition to return that no name had been input.  Still learning how PHP works.  Just trying to follow the tutorial when I didn't get the same result as him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the value to see if it's empty:

```
if(isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name'])) {
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: I really appreciate this example.  Thank you very much for your guidance!

Answer (score 1):

`empty` does what is says, checks if empty (is empty if not existing aswell)

`isset` checks if the var exists, no if anything has been set

`filter_has_var` pretty much the same as isset

place a `print_r($_POST)` at the top of your file, you will understand :)

Comment: Thanks so much for answering so quickly!!  I was wondering if this was the case, but the tutorial video was not getting this result so I was sure I was missing something.